# how to find the function definition and impl in pytorch source code?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to find the function definition and implementation of `torch.real` in the source code, for example, this [line](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/_prims/__init__.py#L803). I thought it should be in the `torch.__init__.py`, but didnt find it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a different `__init__` file since it's implemented in C++

- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/_C/__init__.pyi.in#L1472-L1482
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable.cpp#L1453-L1464